# Bash nested loop get highest

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with a several folders with a bunch of mp3 files each.

This files have names such as "23 - Lecture-1.mp3"

I'm trying to tag the mp3 so I can play the audio files in the right order.

So I need to extract the track number on each (23 on the example above), and compare it with all other files and keep the highest.

My issue is that the highest variable is not persisting after the loop that goes through the files ends, the the highest value is always 0 (the value I initialized it for.)

**So the question is:**

*How do I make bash keep that value outside the loop??*

```
find /media/mdisk/Audio -path "*AIFR*" -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' folder;  do 
    cd "$folder"; 
    highest=0
    find . -name "*.mp3" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;  do 
    basename=`basename "$file"`
    current=$((`echo $basename | cut -d "-" -f1 | sed 's/^0*//'`+ 0));
    highest=$(($highest+0))
    echo "Current is $current"
    if [ "$current" -gt "$highest" ]; then
        highest=$current;
        echo $highest # <--------------- right value here
    fi
    done
    echo "Highest is $highest"; # <----------- value is gone
    echo "";
done
```

Comment: Standard FAQ: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: @kojiro Thanks for the link, sometimes is hard to search for a solution when you don't even know why the issue is happening. I thought it had to do with global variables or something like that, but it didn't seem right. Anyhow, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your pipe from `find` to `while`. Pipes create subshells and variable assignments in subshells don't automagically move up to the parent shell. Instead maybe toss the results of `find` at a variable and have your `While` loop chew away at that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kojiro for the link, here is the solution I went for, for future reference.

```
find /media/mdisk/Audio -path "*AIFR*" -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' folder;  do 
    cd "$folder"; 
    highest=0
    files=`find . -name "*.mp3" -print0`
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file;  do
    basename=`basename "$file"`
    current=$((`echo $basename | cut -d "-" -f1 | sed 's/^0*//'`+ 0));
    highest=$(($highest+0))
    echo "Current is $current"
    if [ "$current" -gt "$highest" ]; then
        highest=$current;
        echo $highest
    fi
    done < <(find . -name "*.mp3" -print0)
    echo "Highest is $highest"; # <--------------- good value now
    echo "";
done
```

Comment: As a side note, what my car needed to play the track in order is to move each track to the usb drive in the order in which I want them to play. I actually read it on the radio manual and it actually work. Crazy what some people do out there...